# wp_editor in theme settings page

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am working on a wordpress theme framework.

I would like to add a wordpress editor to one of the settings pages for (in this case) header content.

I have used information from this tutorial as a base for my settings pages.
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-settings-api-part-2-create-a-top-level-admin-menu/

I can add a text area to save the content but would like to have an editor for ease of adding content for the end user.

In the settings file call back functions I have added an additional case for editor, based on the textarea type

Text area (works fine)

```
case 'textarea':
     $options[$id] = stripslashes($options[$id]);
     $options[$id] = esc_html( $options[$id]);
     echo "<textarea class='textarea$field_class' type='text' id='$id' name='" . $gc_frame_option_name . "[$id]' rows='5' cols='30'>$options[$id]</textarea>";
     echo ($desc != '') ? "<br /><span class='description'>$desc</span>" : "";      
break;
```

editor seciton (displays editor on settings page, but does not save anything to the database)

```
case 'editor':              
    $options[$id] = stripslashes($options[$id]);
    $options[$id] = esc_html( $options[$id]);
    $class = (!empty($class))?$class:'';
    $content = "enter header content here";
    $settings = array(
        'textarea_name' => $gc_frame_option_name.'['.$id.']',
        'editor_class' => $class
    );          
   wp_editor( $content, $id, $settings );
   echo ($desc != '') ? "<br /><span class='description'>$desc</span>" : "";        
break;
```

I have tried just about everything I can think of but I can not get it to save to the database.

Any help would be great.

-Andrew

Answer (score 3):

Please add bellow code to your page

```
case 'editor':              
$options[$id] = stripslashes($options[$id]);
$options[$id] = esc_html( $options[$id]);
$class = (!empty($class))?$class:'';
$content = "enter header content here";
$settings = array(
    'textarea_name' => $gc_frame_option_name.'['.$id.']',
    'editor_class' => $class
);

wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_script( 'editor' );
wp_editor( $content, $id, $settings );

echo ($desc != '') ? "<br /><span class='description'>$desc</span>" : "";
break;
```

It will work, please try and let me know your response.